# Post message to cross-origin iframe in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, angular, google-chrome, iframe

I'm new to JavaScript, and I'm trying to post a message to my iframe in order to scroll it.
I'm trying to achieve it using this code.

```
scroll(i) {
  var src = $("#iframe").attr("src");
  $("#iframe").contentWindow.postMessage(i, src);
}
```

This code is working when launched in Chrome console, but it is not working when launched from the Webapp (using a button).

I get an error saying contentWindow is undefined. Does someone know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason it seems my code was managing `$("#iframe")` as an array.
I got this issue solved by doing this:

```
scroll(i) {
  var src = $("#iframe")[0].attr("src");
  $("#iframe")[0].contentWindow.postMessage(i, src);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(window).scroll(function() {
   scroll("yourHtmlFile.html");
  });    
 function scroll(i){
    $("#iframe").attr("src",i);
 }});
```